# Word not prompting to check in documents on close

Tags: versioning, word, office

I have a client who has two different SharePoint environments (both 2010). In the older environment, when they check out a document and make changes, any time they click on the X to close word they are asked to check the document back in. In the new environment, when they click on the X, it doesn't *always* prompt them but sometimes does, which means they have often dozens of files that remain checked out to the users.

Here is [one source](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/d192bfe2-c60d-4786-a026-81729a021262/exiting-word-doesnt-prompt-sharepoint-checkin-dialog-like-when-closing-word?forum=sharepointgenerallegacy) I found that confirms the inconsistent results.

Is there a way to force that prompt on close? Is this a server side setting, or something I should be looking into on Word?

Thanks!

Comment: Are they always using internet explorer to open the files?

Comment: Aboba, yes. Everybody in the organization should be using IE8 or IE9 for intranet sites.